# PIG: Filter hive table by previous table result

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I need to query one HIVE table and filter the other table with one column of the previous one.

Example:

```
A = LOAD 'db.table1' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

filterA = filter A by (id=='123');

B = LOAD 'db.table2' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

//the problem is here. filterA has many rows. I need to apply filter for each of the row.

filterB = filter B by (id==filterA.id);
```

> **Data in A:**
>
> tabid id dept location
>
> 1     1  IS   SJ
>
> 2     4  CS   SF
>
> 3     5  EC   MD
>
> **Data in B:**
>
> tabid id name   address
>
> 1     4  john   123 S AVE
>
> 2     5  jane   456 N BLVD
>
> 3     9  nick   789 GREAT LAKE DR
>
> **Expected Result:**
>
> tabid id name   address
>
> 1     4  john   123 S AVE
>
> 2     5  jane   456 N BLVD

Comment: Not too sure from your example, but looking at your "Expected Result", it looks like joining DataA and DataB would do?

Comment: I am new in writing PIG scripts. Can you please give me the example for JOIN. I have googled lot of scripting. But none seems working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked in the comment, it sounds like what you're looking for is a join.  Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

```
A = LOAD 'db.table1' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
B = LOAD 'db.table2' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
C = JOIN A by id, B by id;
```

Comment: Sorry for responding this late.

I tried the JOIN, but this gives all the columns from both the tables, I need to get the entire rows of A where id of A is same as id of B.